# webpack config not moving assets to dist folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, production, webpack-production

So after following the guide on the webpack website and following along with Petr's video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdGnYNtuEtE I have the following webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: './dist/bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline:true,
    port: 8081
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/, // /\.esm.js$/
            loader: "babel-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
      {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|less)$/,
        use: [
          {
              loader: "style-loader"
          }, {
              loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
              loader: "less-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 100000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It has come to the production stage of my app, and only the bundle.js file and index.html file exist in the dist folder. This works as it grabs the resources from "**../src/assets/**" folder, however I expect that it should create and copy the assets to an assets folder in the **/dist/** folder.

If anyone can help me with what I am doing wrong in the config I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the devServer option, no files will be written on disk.

```
devServer: {
  inline:true,
  port: 8081
},
```

The web server will work on port 8081 and the generated files will be in memory.